# Fallthrough in switch statement for iOS/Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

Say I have a switch statement with five cases, but only two real methods ever being called, like so:

```
switch (condition) {
    case conditionOutcome1: 

        [self firstMethod];
        break;

    case conditionOutcome2: 
        [self secondMethod];
        break;

    case conditionOutcome3:

        [self firstMethod];
        break;

    case conditionOutcome4: 

        [self firstMethod];

        break;
    case conditionOutcome5: 

        [self secondMethod];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Is it safe to group up the cases, like so?

```
    switch (condition) {

    case conditionOutcome1:
    case conditionOutcome3:
    case conditionOutcome4: 

        [self firstMethod];
        break;

    case conditionOutcome2: 
    case conditionOutcome5: 

        [self secondMethod];
        break;


    default:
        break;
}
```

It works fine, but I've never used it before in objective-c so I'd like to make sure I'm not causing any problems by saving a few lines of code.

Thanks!

Comment: If you used it in C, then why not? In objective-C throw away all starting with @ and you will get clean C.

Comment: Thats a fair point, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to do that.

I've used it before. It stops duplicate code.

Answer (score 11):

Just adding to the other answers, it's called a *fallthrough*, you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).

Comment: You also have the `[[clang::fallthrough]]` to indicate explicit intention when you set your warnings to *paranoid* :) … seen it in the [llvm blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/09/clang-warnings.html) and technical details in the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#non-standard-c-11-attributes)

Answer (score 9):

Yes 100% safe to use

> switch (condition) {
>
> ```
> case conditionOutcome1:
> case conditionOutcome3:
> case conditionOutcome4: 
>
>     [self firstMethod];
>     break;
>
> case conditionOutcome2: 
> case conditionOutcome5: 
>
>     [self secondMethod];
>     break;
>
>
> default:
>     break; }
> ```

This is always used, for multiple `case`s which have same set of actions (duplicate codes) to be performed.

As all the `cases` will be performed untill a `break` get encountered.

Comment: Not to clobber with another answer saying "yes," but just adding a note. You might want to document this in your code by putting a comment between the cases. A simple `/* FALLTHROUGH */` will remind you later that you did in fact mean to write it. The [BSD Style Guide](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=style&sektion=9) requires it.

Comment: @greg: Fall through is a great word that I didnt remember while writing the answer. However I mentioned "all the cases will be executed untill break is found".

Comment: clang also has an explicit directive to indicate such fall through cases `[[clang::fallthrough]]` when you set your warnings to *paranoid* :) … seen it in the [llvm blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/09/clang-warnings.html) and technical details in the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#non-standard-c-11-attributes)