# Make a switch run through every case before ending?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I have made a quiz that utilizes a switch to ask a question. The switch has 100 cases for 100 questions and when called upon it randomly chooses one case to implement. So on my ViewController I have a label for what question will be called upon, and four buttons (for each possible answer). My question is.. is there a way I can utilize a button that will push to a new case within the switch? I am hoping to be able to run through the entire switch before my exit button appears.

Here is a sample of what I have:

```
-(void)Category1{

    NSUInteger QuestionSelected= (arc4random() %100);

    switch (QuestionSelected) {
        case 0:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First question here"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer1Correct = YES;
            CorrectAnswerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer to be displayed"];
            break;
        case 1:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First question here"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Possible answer selection here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer1Correct = YES;
            CorrectAnswerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer to be displayed"];
            break;
```

Please if you have an answer please explain how the answer works. I am still new to objective-c and am building this app for shear learning. Or am I just missing an obvious answer? I am hoping to use a button to implement this if possible because I have it set so that once you select an answer, the  Answer1-4 buttons will disappear and the CorrectAnswerDisplay label appears showing the correct answer. Thank you guys so much for you help! This site has been a lifesaver and I have been trying to help out others as best I can!

EDIT: Here are pictures on how it runs right now:

[image: Category Selection]

[image: Question]

[image: Correct/Incorrect Screen]

And right now I have it set to go back to the Category selection. It is that correct/incorrect screen that makes it hard for me. I am trying to get the end result be a Next button instead of a Next Category button and run through all the questions before it gets to that.

Comment: If you want to fall through cases, just remove the `break;`s.

Comment: I don't think a switch is at all what you want. Your code violates DRY principles. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) You really do want a data driven model. It will seem to you like a lot more work right now but in the end it won't be. For example, lets say you have 100 cases there, but now we need to add a 5th answer. What are you going to do?

Comment: I have actions that run whether they get an answer correct or not. For instance my if they chose the correct answer if it was the first one, the Answer1Correct BOOL is set to YES and it will run -(void)RightAnswer which will hide the four buttons and display the right answer and add a point to their score. I don't want to lose the ability to show the correct answer. If there was a way to make a "Next" button of some sort to continue with the switch would be ideal.

Comment: There is to much to tell for an answer. You are writing an application with an UI. These are event driven. You do not push to another "state", your app is not linear. The user input pushes your apple there. Beside this your code is not good. Put Q&As in an array and use an index on it.

Comment: John Green, I am interested. For this exact quiz, once it is made it is made. It has 780 questions already typed up and ready and is based off a standard test that won't change for a couple years. But I do have more quizzes to make and am trying to learn efficiency.

Comment: To be honest, I tried using Arrays, but they confuse the crap out of me. I always ended up going back to this method because it was so basic I was able to conform it to what made sense to me and get an end result I like.. until I realized it was annoying to go back to the category selection screen every time I answered a question.

Answer (score 2):

What @H2CO3 said about removing the `break` statements is correct. Doing so will fall through the cases, [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136395/fallthrough-in-switch-statement-for-ios-objective-c).

That being said, I think you're trying to solve this in the wrong way. In stead of hard coding all of these values, you should try a more dynamic approach using an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary can store info about the questions and the possible answers. Doing so, you can replace your entire switch with something roughly like this:

```
- (void)categoryOne
{
    NSUInteger questionSelected = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.arrayOfQuestions.count);

    NSDictionary *thisQuestion = self.arrayOfQuestions[questionSelected];

    [questionsLabel setText:thisQuestion[@"question"]];

    [answerOneButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerTwoButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerThreeButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerFourButton setTitle:thisQuestion[@"answer4"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    answer1Correct = YES;
    correctAnswerDisplay.text = thisQuestion[@"answer"];
}
```

As additional side notes, instances and instance methods should use camelCase starting with lower case letters, as is the convention in Objective C, and there is no need to use `+[NSString stringWithFormat:` if you're only setting the contents of a single string.

Comment: Okay so this makes a little sense to me. I am more trying to wrap my head around what is going on when this runs to help me further understand in the future. So integrating this.. what additional things does this require me to define and why? I am not familiar with NSDictionary, would this be defined within the .m or does it require more work? I am sorry, I am trying to get a better understanding of what is going on and I still only have very remedial knowledge on programming. Thank you so much for taking to time to explain

Comment: So looking at this. We're using NSDictionary to save [@"question"] as the label of thisQuestion. I think I understand that part. It is the NSUInteger I think that I am tripping up on how it works. We are setting up an NSUInteger called questionSelected that randomizes the questions in the category. What is the arrayOfQuestions.count?

Comment: @JoeMarion You'll need to declare an instance of NSArray to store all of your dictionaries in, the scope of which is up to you. And an NSDictionary is just a data structure, but instead of storing data by index, like an array, dictionaries store data in a key-value relationship. This means that when you use `thisQuestion[@"answer"]`, you're asking the dictionary for the value it's storing for the "answer" key. And no, you don't have to set up arrayOfQuestions.count.

Comment: Count is a property of NSArray that merely returns the number of objects in the array. In this case, we're using this to get a random number in between 0 and the total count of objects in the array. That way, when we access the object at that random index in the array, the index will never be outside of the arrays bounds (which causes a crash).

Comment: That makes sense. So going from this to implementing it, how does this work when it implements answer1Correct. When it runs that BOOL that eventually will hide the four buttons and display the correct answer. In addition it adds to your score. I added pictures that show what happens as of right now when a correct answer (or incorrect really) is selected. I don't want it to skip this part because it is supposed to help them learn.

Comment: For your example would it the NSArray that needed to be define be arrayOfQuestions? Or would it be the NSUInteger questionSelected? Once again thank you for the help. I am beginning to feel like the information is there, it is making the logic of it make sense to me.

Comment: @JoeMarion I hate to leave you hanging like this but, I'm going to be off the computer for a little while, but seeing what you're attempting to make, I'd love to help more. Either later tonight or tomorrow morning, I'll put together a sample project demonstrating all this and put it up on github.

Comment: No, thank you very much! I have redone this damn app 3-4 times and haven't been able to figure this last part with what I know. I have learned so much from making this and from what I can see where you have been going with this I am learning a little more on the difference between hardcoding and dynamic which is great. I have just tried to brute force my way through this. If you want I can send you most of my source (minus the boring stuff) so that you can see what I have got and compare it.

Comment: I have github too if you wanted to coordinate anything. This could definitely be a big learning point for me.

Comment: So when I am defining the NSArray, would it be a @property with arrayOfQuestions? I have been messing around with it all day and the more I work with it, the more I am understanding. I am just looking through different tutorials I can find online.